# Linkedin listing company jobs

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the list of jobs of a company.
However we got some doubts on how to do that...

I'm using this example to get the list of companies:
"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/xxxxx/updates?event-type=job-posting"

1. The user always have to login to generate the access token, is it possible to get the list of jobs without the access token?
2. Even after the authentication, only users that are admin to the company linkedin, can see the job offers. Normal users cant see the jobs list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's my experience too that you can only get Job updates for companies you have the admin permissions of. Furthermore this is consistent with what is described in the docs:

> Required permission: rw_company_admin
>
> Whether set as a default
>   permission in your app settings or requested specifically via the
>   scope argument during your authentication process, you will need to
>   request the rw_company_admin member permission in order for your
>   application to successfully make these API calls to LinkedIn.
>
> In order to perform any of the company page management API
>   calls below, the authenticated LinkedIn user making the requests must
>   be an administrator of the target company.

See: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages

Please note that the v1 API seems to be kind of deprecated. Better be prepared that is ceases to work at any time.

See: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates